# Vertical align for tbody

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table separated by thead and tbody. The text I have in tbody is vertically centered. I want to have it displayed at the top of the tbody.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>.... </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <p> Hello!
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried doing something like:

```
tbody { vertical-align:top;}
```

But that doesnt work

Comment: `<tbody valign="top">`

Comment: doesnt work. sadface

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `valign` as it works correctly, the problem is the element `h1` has a margin by default, you should set it to `0`:

```css
h1 {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>.... </td>
        <td>.... </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody valign="top"> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <p> Hello!</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            A
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>  
</table>
```